# Add Menu Item in File Menu in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am developing a Power Point Add-in (Using C#) in which I have to add a Custom Menu Entry in the "File" Menu.

I followed all the steps in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608602(v=vs.100).aspx

but my menu is not showing up in Powerpoint.

Do I need to anything extra here ?

Comment: Are you developing a Powerpoint 2007 addin using VSTO in Visual Studio 2008? If not, what versions?

Comment: @Nilzor, I am developing a PowerPoint 2010 Addin using VS 2010.
Now I can see a Menu Item called "Add-Ins" and under that My Menu Item can be seen, where as I would like to have my Menu Entry should be visible in File menu Itself.

Comment: I don't think that is possible in Powerpoint 2010. The documentation you linked to states the following: "For Office 2010 projects, controls that you add to the File tab appear in a group named Add-ins."

Answer (score 0):

You must check i would my add-in to lad the host

Link of full sample : http://csharpmentor.blogspot.fr/2009/05/how-to-create-powerpoint-add-in-in-cnet.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Nilzor, I found the Solution, It is called Backstage view

We need to add the  in the XML to make it work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <backstage>
    <tab id="MyBackstageTab"
           label="My Tab"
           getVisible="MyBackstageTab_GetVisible">
    </tab>
  </backstage>
</customUI>
```